# Python 2.7: Setting I/O Encoding, ‚Äô?

Tags: python, character-encoding

Attempting to write a line to a text file in Python 2.7, and have the following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
...
f = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'output.txt'), 'w')
f.write('Smith’s BaseBall Cap') // Note the strangely shaped apostrophe
```

However, in output.txt, I get `Smith‚Äôs BaseBall Cap`, instead. Not sure how to correct this encoding problem? Any protips with this sort of issue?

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: Oh shoot, 2.7! Thanks for the catch

Comment: On OS X 10.6, would this not occur on other operating systems? that seems strange

Comment: On another system, it’s more likely that you’d get `â` instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have declared your file to be encoded with UTF-8, so your byte-string literal is in UTF-8.  The curly apostrophe is [U+2019](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm).  In UTF-8, this is encoded as three bytes, \xE2\x80\x99.  Those three bytes are written to your output file.  Then, when you examine the output file, it is interpreted as something other than UTF-8, and you see the three incorrect characters instead.

In [Mac OS Roman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman), those three bytes display as `‚Äô`.

Your file is a correct UTF-8 file, but you are viewing it incorrectly.

Comment: That's true, but if he then writes the string using the normal file operations, it should be written as-is and remain with the UTF-8 bytes in the output file.

Comment: @BrenBarn: you're assuming the output file is being displayed as UTF-8, it's not, it's Mac OS Roman.

Comment: Oh, it does seem to be a problem with the software I am using to view the output (TextEdit), if I cat output.txt in the command prompt, it works well

Comment: @zhuyxn, you need to update or change your text editor. The world would be so much nicer if every single application assumed UTF-8 by default.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple possibilities, but the first one to check is that the output file actually contains what you think it does.  Are you sure you're not viewing the file with the wrong encoding?  Some editors have an option to choose what encoding you're viewing the file in.  The editor needs to know the file's encoding, and if it interprets the file as being in some other encoding than UTF-8, it will display the wrong thing even though the contents of the file are correct.

When I run your code (on Python 2.6) I get the correct output in the file.  Another thing to try:  Use the `codecs` module to open the file for UTF-8 writing: `f = codecs.open("file.txt", "w", "utf-8").  Then declare the string as a unicode string with`u"'Smith’s BaseBall Cap'"`.

Comment: OS X uses MacRoman as its default encoding. `>>> print u'’'.encode('utf-8').decode('macroman')`
`‚Äô`

Comment: Sure, but the question what encoding is being assumed by the particular program being used to read the file.

Comment: It's OS X. The program therefore is TextEdit, and the encoding is MacRoman.

Comment: Correct, using TextEdit to open the output, just realized the output is correct if I cat output.txt in the command line.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what specifically does codecs.open() mean by returning a wrapped version defined by the codec (from documentation)? It seems like lines of output are disappearing if I apply this line.

Comment: `codecs.open` allows you to write unicode strings (not UTF-8 strings, but actual unicode objects) to the file.  The 'wrapped object" handles encoding of the unicode to the encoding you select (e.g., UTF-8).  That's why you have to pass it unicode objects, not encoded bytestrings.